# ValueError at /create The view djangoproj1.view.stinsert didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have created simple student details form for getting marks, name, and dob of the student. I am very very new to django. Please help to clear this error

IN view.py

```
    from django.shortcuts import render
    from djangoproj1.models import crudst
    from django.contrib import messages

    def stdisplay(request):
        results=crudst.objects.all()
        return render(request,"index.html",{"crudst":results})

    def stinsert(request):
       if request.method=="POST":
          if request.POST.get('stname') and  request.POST.get('stregno') and 
              request.POST.get('stdob') and request.POST.get('stsubmath') and 
              request.POST.get('stsubenglish') and 
              request.POST.get('stsubsocial') and 
              request.POST.get('stsubscience'):
              savest=crudst()
              savest.stname = request.POST.get('stname')
              savest.stdob = request.POST.get('stdob')
              savest.stsubmath = request.POST.get('stsubmath')
              savest.stsubenglish = request.POST.get('stsubenglish')
              savest.stsubsocial = request.POST.get('stsubsocial')
              savest.stsubscience = request.POST.get('stsubscience')
              sum = int(savest.stsubmath ) + int(savest.stsubenglish) +int(savest.stsubsocial)+ int(savest.stsubscience)
              avg = sum/4
              savest.staverage = avg
              # grade=""
              #savest.stgrade = grade
              savest.save()
              messages.success(request,"The Record "+savest.stname+ " is saved succesfully.")
              return render(request,"create.html")
     else:
            return render(request,"create.html")
```

Error message

```
ValueError at /create
The view djangoproj1.view.stinsert didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Request Method: POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/create
Django Version: 3.2.2
Exception Type: ValueError
Exception Value:    
The view djangoproj1.view.stinsert didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.
Exception Location: C:\Users\Raji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py, line 309, in check_response
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Raji\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe
Python Version: 3.9.2
```

please help me to clear this error. IDK where I have done the mistake. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Your nested `if` block does not have a `else` condition. So you could end up returning nothing, hence `None`

```py
def stinsert(request):
   if request.method=="POST":
      if request.POST.get('stname') and  request.POST.get('stregno') and 
          request.POST.get('stdob') and request.POST.get('stsubmath') and 
          request.POST.get('stsubenglish') and 
          request.POST.get('stsubsocial') and 
          request.POST.get('stsubscience'):
          savest=crudst()
          savest.stname = request.POST.get('stname')
          savest.stdob = request.POST.get('stdob')
          savest.stsubmath = request.POST.get('stsubmath')
          savest.stsubenglish = request.POST.get('stsubenglish')
          savest.stsubsocial = request.POST.get('stsubsocial')
          savest.stsubscience = request.POST.get('stsubscience')
          sum = int(savest.stsubmath ) + int(savest.stsubenglish) +int(savest.stsubsocial)+ int(savest.stsubscience)
          avg = sum/4
          savest.staverage = avg
          # grade=""
          #savest.stgrade = grade
          savest.save()
          messages.success(request,"The Record "+savest.stname+ " is saved succesfully.")
          return render(request,"create.html")
      else:
          # ---> Return something here <---
 else:
        return render(request,"create.html")
```